# Namespace is not defined for type org.comp.item

Tags: hyperledger-composer

```
namespace org.comp.item

/* ASSETS */
asset Item identified by itemId {
    o String itemId
    o String itemData
}
```

---

```
namespace org.comp.transaction
import org.comp.item

/**
 * JUST FOR INITIALIZING A DEMO
*/
transaction SetupDemoItem {
}

transaction Get {
}

transaction CreateItem {
    o Item newItem
}
```

I have one cto file called item with a asset called item. And in other file called transaction a couple transactions.

In the transaction file I have a transaction that needs and asset from the other file. But I can´t make the transaction because i can´t do the import. That the error:

> Error found!
>
> t: Namespace is not defined for type org.comp.item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `import org.comp.item.*` to bring in all the classes from that file or `import org.comp.item.Item`.

Your class will then be called `"$class": "org.comp.item.Item"`

Comment: That´s it. Thank you ;D